# How to debug a program that doesn’t throw any error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, asp.net-mvc-3

I’m having trouble to find a bug in my application.

The problem is random and don’t throw any error. The web site just keeps loading and loading and eventually gets a timeout.

Is a web application using MVC 3 in VS 2010 Pro.

Some time ago, I see a friend to write something in the url, and gets all the trace of the program…
Sadly, I don’t remember what the command was.

Anyone has an idea of what command is it?

Any suggestion on what to use to debug?

Thanks!

Edgar.

UPDATE!

I finally found the command... is trace.axd

But Its behave the same way... sometimes load without problems and show me all the trace info... and sometimes.. it keep loading and loading...

Maybe something related with IIS?

Comment: Attach to the "loading and loading" site's process using the debugger and hit pause to see what it is up to.

Comment: I tried that... but I get the "no source available" error..

Answer (score 1):

Turn on break on every thrown exception, run your application in debug mode and wait. If it executes too long then pause application and check where you are or wait for exception that is handled somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend may have had something like the following built into his application, to dynamically set tracing on.

```
Trace.IsEnabled = Request.QueryString["trace"] != null ? true : false;
```

This provides info only if the page is fully loaded. It's probably best if you use the VS debugger to step through code.

If all you loops look ok, investigate code that could result in circular references or deadlocks. These can be difficult to spot sometimes, look for functions or constructors that require results from a calling class. So code that needs the result from a function which in turn need results from the first.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this sounds like you have an infinite loop somewhere.

Look at the code that runs when you visit the URL that gives you trouble. See if there is any loops in there (`for`/`while`). If yes, see why if they never exit. You can do this by putting a breakpoint inside the loop and examining its behavior over the iterations.

Comment: Thanks! The the application runs perfect about 50% of the time, and 50% failure... with the same exact parameters..

Answer (score 0):

in MVC the bugs you do not see are most of time (especially in Razor and Ajax work) view compile errors. Sometimes syntax bugs on views just does not show that view and do not stop working.

Try that:

put a breakpoint in view.
If program stops in there it means this view is working. Othervise there is a syntax error in this view.

Another way to see some bug information more than in visual studio is use browser tools.
I use google Chrome. Just open developer tools in it. Open network. And do your request. It will list the requests and responses. Click the response and see the information. After style (it is written Verdana etc) read exception details. Sometimes there is more information :)

I am using MVC 3 in Razor from start. So this is a small bug in asp.net mvc.